# Group_by inside a function

Tags: r

I am trying to use the group_by function inside of a function but it doesn't seem to work. I found an example in another post as below (this works) :-

```
dat <- mtcars[c(2:4,11)]


grp <- function(x) {
  group_by(dat,!!as.name(x)) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  mutate(pc=scales::percent(n/sum(n))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% head()
}


lapply(colnames(dat), grp)
```

What I don't understand is why do I need to data frame name in the group_by function - doesn't group_by function work this way :-

```
data %>% group_by(lgID) %>% summarise(mean_run = mean(HR))
```

where the data is piped to the group_by function?

Also, why do I need '!!as.name(x)' - what does this do?

Further, why does the version shown above work and this version shown below doesn't?

```
grp <- function(x) {
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  mutate(pc=scales::percent(n/sum(n))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% head()
}


lapply(colnames(dat), grp)
```

Obviously I am missing something here!

Best regards

Deepak

Comment: OK. Fair enough. what if I had function(dat, x) {dat %>% group_by(x) %>%...}; Sould that work? Also, what if the group_by column is a numeric field? Why is "!!as.name(x)" needed?

Comment: That would be better with data argument.  What are the choices you have for passing the 'x'.  Would that be always unquoted, quoted (strings) or numeric index?

Comment: Can you check my solution posted below.  It works for strings and numeric index

Comment: I tried but this failed - lapply(colnames(dat), grp, dat) - to the above function with 'dat' as a parameter. In my case, the list would be a list of 5 data frames and the group by field would be numeric. Like so :- 'test <- sapply(get("thisobjectname")[[1]], f)' and the function like this :- 'f <- function(x) {group_by(RowNum) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>% summarize(mean(x$RowNum)}'

Comment: Can you check my solution posted below.  Both of them are working for me

Comment: Saw your solution after posting. Sorry - just about to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to pass both index and strings as 'x', wrap it inside `across` within `group_by`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.0.0

f1 <- function(data, x) {
    data %>%
     group_by(across(all_of(x))) %>%
     summarise(n=n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
     mutate(pc=scales::percent(n/sum(n))) %>% 
     arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
     head()
}
```

If we have an older version, use `group_by_at(x)`

-apply the function

```
out1 <- lapply(colnames(dat), function(x) f1(dat, x))
```

Or use index

```
out2 <- lapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) f1(dat, i))

identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

-output

```
out1[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl     n pc   
#  <dbl> <int> <chr>
#1     8    14 43.8%
#2     4    11 34.4%
#3     6     7 21.9%

out2[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl     n pc   
#  <dbl> <int> <chr>
#1     8    14 43.8%
#2     4    11 34.4%
#3     6     7 21.9%
```

Comment: Tried the first one, came up with this error - 'Error in across(all_of(x)) : could not find function "across" '

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Your `dplyr` version would be old.  It is from dplyr 1.0.0 version

Comment: Will try updating and rerun later. Will let you know!

Comment: Any idea why I get this error - ' Error in data %>% group_by(across(all_of(x))) %>% summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%" '

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Have you loaded `library(dplyr)`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to update. Looks like I have permission issues. This is work laptop

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal In that case, change it to `group_by_at` i.e. `group_by_at(x)`

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks!

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal it is working for me.  I assume that your dplyr version would be  0.8 or so

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal can you please confirm whether the group_by_at is working. thanks